# MYsql Pattern Printing

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to print pattern in this format in MY SQL . Here is my code :

```
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

Mysql code :

```
declare @i int 
select @i = 20
while @i>0
begin
print repeat('*' ,@i)
set @i=@i-1;
end ;
```

I'm getting error in solving this . Please someone tell me the changes needed to make this work

Comment: MySQL does nopt support anonymous codeblocks. *I'm getting error* Provide complete error message text. *I need to print pattern in this format in MY SQL .* Precise MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql does not have PRINT

Comment: Please never say you got an error.  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SET @maxlen := 5;
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
> cte AS (
>     SELECT @maxlen num
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT num - 1 FROM cte WHERE num > 1
> )
> SELECT REPEAT('*', num)
> FROM cte
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPEAT('*', num) |
> | :--------------- |
> | *****            |
> | ****             |
> | ***              |
> | **               |
> | *                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e351a02d5f57b5d0ca67889df24e023c)*